# sql merge wouldn't except update statement?

Tags: sql, merge

I have a situation where I need to insert data from table1 to table2. Before insert check if a certain row already exist in the table2.

Conditions are if:
1) the values of id and ahccs are same in both the table, then don't do anything.
2) the value of id are same but ahccs are different, then set flag ='z' and insert the same  id with the new ahccs value.

I am using SQLSERVER 2008 R2. How could I achieve this?

I might need something like this.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE 
(id int not null, ahccs int not null, info varchar(25), flag varchar(2))
DECLARE @table2 TABLE 
(id int not null, ahccs int not null, info varchar(25), flag varchar(2))

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES(1, 1223, 'et', 'X')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES(2, 321, 'et', 'X')
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES(3, 134, 'et', 'X' )
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES(4, 168, 'et', 'X' )
INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES(5, 123, 'et', 'X' )


INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES(1, 1223, 'dt', 'y' )
INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES(2, 456, 'dt', 'y' )
INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES(3, 123, 'dt', 'y' )
INSERT INTO @table2
VALUES(4, 193, 'dt', 'y' )
--SELECT * FROM @table1

SELECT * FROM @table2



MERGE
INTO    @table2 t2
USING   @table1 t1
ON      t2.id = t1.id 
WHEN MATCHED AND t2.ahccs != t1.ahccs THEN
UPDATE
SET     flag = 'z'
INSERT VALUES (t2.id, t1.ahccs, t1.info, 'l');
```

The two issues I am having are:
1) Merge doesn't support multiple steps, I believe.
2) Update is not allowed in WHEN NOT MATCHED case.

Please advise.

Thank You.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want as the result table on your example. Of course that it doesn't let you `UPDATE` when the results don't match, because what row are you gonna update, all the table?. What is the desired behavior when the rows match?, what columns do you need to ÙPDATE`?

Comment: Conditions are if:
1) the values of id and ahccs are same in both the table, then don't do anything.
2) the value of id are same but ahccs are different, then set flag ='z' and insert the same  id with the new ahccs value.

Comment: I have updated the question, made some mistakes there.

Comment: Are you wanting to update `flag = 'z'` in the source table, target table, or both?

Comment: re 2): An UPDATE does not make any sense for "WHEN NOT MATCHED". If no rows are found  there is nothing that could be updated.

Comment: we are setting the old entry for an id to be void in table2 and adding a new entry for the same id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I understand the requirements now. You want to update records in table2 where the id matches but ahccs does not, setting the flag to 'z'. Additionally, for these mismatches, a new row should be inserted into table2 with the same id but the ahccs from table1, and a flag of 'l'.

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (id int, ahccs int, info varchar(25), flag varchar(2))
MERGE
INTO    @table2 t2
USING   @table1 t1
ON      t2.id = t1.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (t1.id, t1.ahccs, t1.info, t1.flag)
WHEN MATCHED and t2.ahccs <> t1.ahccs THEN
    UPDATE SET flag = 'z'
output inserted.id, t1.ahccs, t1.info, inserted.flag
into @tmp;

insert into @table2
select id, ahccs, info, 'l' as flag
from @tmp
where flag = 'z' -- don't insert what we've already inserted
```

Comment: Do you think this will play like this? When not matched the flag for the original id in the target table will be set to z and then the new values of info and ahccs will be inserted for the same id into the target table?

Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am understanding the reqs better as I keep playing with them.

Comment: I think this does what you want. When there's no match for id and ahccs, a matching record is inserted into table2 with flag = 'l' and table1 is updated so flag = 'z'.

Comment: the flag is set to z in table2 also, not in table1. so we are setting the old entry for an id to be void in table2 and adding a new entry for the same id.

Comment: Conditions are if: 1) the values of id and ahccs are same in both the table, then don't do anything. 2) the value of id are same but ahccs are different, then set flag ='z' and insert the same id with the new ahccs value.

Comment: I think I got it now. Should flag = 'z' in the newly inserted row as well?

Comment: no. It is set to l. :) to identify that it is a newly added row with same id.

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sweet you are amazing, if it is not too much to ask, may you please add one more clause where no matches are found then just insert the values from the source table to the target. I have already accepted your answer and it works. One added help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Updated. Keep in mind that output will also create rows when inserting in the WHEN NOT MATCHED clause - I added something to take care of that so you don't end up with duplicates.